# .net core api returns clients index.html file for every request

Tags: c#, .net, api, react-redux

I setup a reactredux/dotnetcore app with the `dotnet new reactredux` command. I'm trying to test my api but whenever I try to fetch something, the only thing I get back is the index.html from the react client. Even for endpoints I have not specified.

I have my app running on localhost 5000 and 5001 and for both I get the same result.

Did I forget to set some setting?
Am I using the wrong address? Where can I find the right one.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET Core SPA templates will redirect you to the SPA index.html static page whenever the MVC backend doesn't have a matching route for the request. Add this controller to your application and see if you can get a response from it. If it works compare the changes to the rest of the controllers you're calling:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Test() => Content("Hello World!");
}
```